# How to delete the words between two delimiters?

Tags: python

I have a noisy data..something like

```
<@ """@$ FSDF >something something <more noise>
```

Now I just want to extract `"something something"`. 
Is there a way on how to delete the text between those two delimiters `"<"` and `">"`?

Comment: is the data always of that form with one per line?

Comment: Do you want to extract "something something" or delete the text between the "<" and ">" delimiters?

Comment: Hi.. The data has multiple lines..basically a huge file
I want to extract "something something" but using re and beautiful soup.. suddenly leaves me with blank file.. not quite sure why.. But if I can erase the text between "<" and ">" then that also serves the same purpose :)

Comment: @Fraz BeautifulSoup handles the matching tags in an html source, so it may not come to help parsing random text enclosed by '<' and '>'.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<@ """@$ FSDF >something something <more noise>'
>>> re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', s)
'something something '
```

[Update]

If you tried a pattern like `<.+>`, where the dot means any character and the plus sign means one or more, you know it does not work.

```
>>> re.sub(r'<.+>', s, '')
''
```

Why!?! It happens because regular expressions are "greedy" by default. The expression will match anything until the end of the string, including the `>` - and this is not what we want. We want to match `<` and stop on the next `>`, so we use the `[^x]` pattern which means "any character but x" (x being `>`).

The `?` operator turns the match "non-greedy", so this has the same effect:

```
>>> re.sub(r'<.+?>', '', s)
'something something '
```

The previous is more explicit, this one is less typing; be aware that `x?` means zero or one occurrence of x.

Comment: If every regex answer EXPLAINED why the regex works in the first place, like you did, SO would be a much happier place. +1!

Answer (score 23):

Of course, you can use regular expressions.

```
import re
s = #your string here
t = re.sub('<.*?>', '', s)
```

The above code should do it.

Answer (score 5):

First thank you Paulo Scardine, I used your re to do great thing. The idea was to have tag free LibreOffice po file for printing purposes. And I made the following script which will clean the help file for smaller and easier ones.

```
import re
f = open('a.csv')
text = f.read()
f.close()

clean = re.sub('<[^>]+>', ' ', text)

f = open('b.csv', 'w')
f.write(clean)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
my_str = '<@ """@$ FSDF >something something <more noise>'
re.sub('<.*?>', '', my_str)
'something something '
```

The `re.sub` function takes a regular expresion and replace all the matches in the string with the second parameter. In this case, we are searching for all characters between `<` and `>` (`'<.*?>'`) and replacing them with nothing (`''`).

The `?` is used in `re` for non-greedy searches.

More about the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

---

If that "noises" are actually html tags, I suggest you to look into [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 2):

Just for interest, you could write some code such as:

```
with open('blah.txt','w') as f:
    f.write("""<sdgsa>one<as<>asfd<asdf>
<asdf>two<asjkdgai><iasj>three<fasdlojk>""")

def filter_line(line):
    count=0
    ignore=False
    result=[]
    for c in line:
        if c==">" and count==1:
            count=0
            ignore=False
        if not ignore:
            result.append(c)
        if c=="<" and count==0:
            ignore=True
            count=1
    return "".join(result)

with open('blah.txt') as f:
    print "".join(map(filter_line,f.readlines()))

>>> 
<>one<>asfd<>
<>two<><>three<>
```

Comment: Yeah I decided they may want that second ">" e.g. if you have <hello>myname->bob<hello>, you would get myname->bob, in the other situation you would just get 'bob'. It's really never ideal to parse broken xml. My code also fails if there is a new line character between the "<" ">" tags. Thanks for reading my code though

Comment: the question title and the description do not correlate. In the questions he wants to delete the text between the two delimiters , but in the description he wants to keep the text