# Most pythonic way to delete text between two delimiters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to remove wiki formatting from some text so it can be parsed.

What is the most pythonic way to remove two delimiters ('[[' and ']]') all the text between them? The given string **will** contain multiple occurrences of delimiter pairs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: delete the words between two delimeters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784396/python-delete-the-words-between-two-delimeters)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regular expressions are a good match for your problem.

```
>>> import re
>>> input_str = 'foo [[bar]] baz [[etc.]]'
```

If you are wanting to remove the whole `[[...]]`, which is I think what you are asking about,

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[\[.*?\]\]', '', input_str)
'foo  baz '
```

If you are wanting to leave the contents of the `[[...]]` in,

```
>>> re.sub(r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', r'\1', input_str)
'foo bar baz etc.'
```