# Remove Wiki markup from string in Python

Tags: python

I have a string containing information downloaded from a Wikia page.

In order to parse its contents, how would I strip down all Wiki formatting from the page, leaving only the raw text?

Here's an example of what might turn up:

```
#REDIRECT[[Blah]]

{{
I have some stuff in here
}}
[[I also have some stuff in here|and here]]
[[http://blehthisisfake.com Link to a fake website]]

&lt;span class="plainlinks"&gt;This is quite useless. Why was [[this page]] even created?&lt;/span&gt;

&lt;nowiki&gt;There are more HTML tags, they should probably all be stripped...&lt;/nowiki&gt;

There is random text in here. bleh bleh bleh

I'm not sure what single [brackets] do, but they should be stripped too...
```

Expected output:

```
There is random text in here. bleh bleh bleh

I'm not sure what single do, but they should be stripped too...
```

Is there a module that could do this?

Comment: can you paste some sample text?

Comment: There's a lot of possibilities of what it could contain, but I'll try to whip something up. Also, I was kind of wanting a module that could do this, but it doesn't look like there is one.

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm working on what you are talking about now.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059793/most-pythonic-way-to-delete-text-between-two-delimiters) is you looking for? Try to play with regex this way.

Comment: I made that question before I realized just how much wiki formatting there is...

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for "python wiki parser" turns up [this code](https://pypi.org/project/wikitextparser/), which strips and replaces the tags (see the source code in the link for details).

Comment: @cheezy how do you plan to know what to remove if you don't parse it?

Comment: As @jordanm says, you can't avoid parsing it to do what you want.  The question here is how?  The answer is the parser (speaking broadly, as wiki markup can usually be parsed with a finite automaton, which would often be called a "lexer" in the compiler world) delivers up a series of recognized pieces, like: START-LINK link text END-LINK.  Output everything that's "text" and not wiki markup, and you've got what you want.

Comment: The link sends you to a site offering free robux. Not quite what I was looking for, but thanks for the laugh.

Here's a link to the official site: https://pypi.org/project/wikitextparser/

Comment: Amazing what can happen in 11 years.