# Using regex for two delimiters to extract strings

Tags: python, regex

The question [How to delete the words between two delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784396/how-to-delete-the-words-between-two-delimiters) was really helpful to me.

So I have a string like this:

```
string = $blabla$blav:1085$350_X[7:0]
```

I am trying to remove whatever is inside the `'[]'` to make the whole thing be `$blabla$blav:1085$350_X`.

I tried all these:

```
re.sub('[[^]]+]', '', string)
re.sub(r'[.+?]', '', string)
re.sub('[.*?]', '', string)
```

Any method to do it with regex involving one step please.

Also, I need to capture that string`[7:0]` for later use.

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the regex `\[([0-9]+\:[0-9]+)\]$`. It matches `[X:Y]` where `X` and `Y` are numbers and the whole thing is at the end of a string. There is only one group in the regex that returns the two numbers `X:Y` without the `[` and `]`

Use this to replace the string:

```
import re
re.sub('\[([0-9]+\:[0-9]+)\]$', '', string)
```

You can use this `\[([0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)\]$` to match the two numbers in two groups.

```
numbersRegex = re.search('\[([0-9]+)\:([0-9]+)\]$', string)
number1 = numbersRegex.group(1)
number2 = numbersRegex.group(2)
bothNumbers = numbersRegex.group(0)
```

It is important to use regex instead of just string indexes in case the numbers are two or more digits. Otherwise, it is fine to indices.

If the `[X:Y]` is not at the end of the string, just remove the `$` from the regex.

You can use [this website](https://regexr.com/) and paste the regex there. It provides explanation and a text field to test it.

Comment: if the string is string = $blabla$blav:1085$350_X[12:0] then it is not working ..what to do ?

Comment: Hey! there was a mistake in my regex, I've fixed it now. Should work with double and multiple digit numbers. The + sign should have been placed after the [. Please use https://regexr.com/ to check your regexes. It provides an explanation of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsplit` with `maxsplit=1` to make sure it only split on last `[`,

```
string = "$blabla$blav:1085$350_X[7:0]"
s_string = string.rsplit('[', maxsplit=1)

left = s_string[0]
right = "[" + s_string[-1]
print(left)
print(right)


# output

$blabla$blav:1085$350_X
[7:0]
```

If you must use regex, then try positive lookahead to match last occurrence of `[`,

```
import re

string = "$blabla$blav:1085$350_X[7:0]"
regex = r'(^.*(?=\[))(.*)'
ss = re.match(regex, string)

left = ss.group(1)
right = ss.group(2)


print(left)
print(right)


# output

$blabla$blav:1085$350_X
[7:0]
```

Comment: Thanks but their position not always gonna be same.

Comment: @zaki, i have also added regex answer if you like

Answer (score 0):

```
string= '$blabla$blav:1085$350_X[7:0]'

cut_string = string.split('[')[0] # = '$blabla$blav:1085$350_X'

bracket_data = string.split('[')[1].replace(']', '') # = '7:0'
```

Dirty, but it just werks.

Comment: What happens if there is another `[` or `]` in the string?

Comment: Thanks, I solved it this way too but I wanted to solve it with regex in one line preferably .

Comment: Check my answer then ;)