# How to remove multiple quotes and lines within double quotes from a .txt file in python code?

Tags: python, methods, comments

I have a txt file with several strings and some of them are enclosed in double (or triple) quotes and would like to remove what is inside the quotation marks and remain only the quotation marks. Example:

```
""" aaaa """

bbbbb
ccccc

"""
dddddd
"""
```

and should look like this:

```
""" """

bbbbb
ccccc

"""

"""
```

I have to do this in python. Does anyone have any idea of a module that does this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete the words between two delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784396/how-to-delete-the-words-between-two-delimiters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the following regex:

```
s = '''
""" aaaa """

bbbbb
ccccc

"""
dddddd
"""
'''

import re
print(re.sub(r'(\"{2,3}[\s\n]*).*?([\n\s]*\"{2,3})', r'\1\2', s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

this outputs:

```
"""  """

bbbbb
ccccc

"""

"""
```

EDIT: to match multiline inside the quotes regex should be updated. Here is the example:

```
s = '''
""" aaaa """

bbbbb
ccccc

"""
dddddd
bb
"""
'''

import re

print(re.sub(r'(\"{2,3}[\s\n]*)(?:.*?[\s\n]*)*([\n\s]*\"{2,3})', r'\1\2', s, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

gives output:

```
""" """

bbbbb
ccccc

"""
"""
```

Comment: oh yes, it worked though, when I have the following situation: I have more than one line inside the quotes, example:


"""
dddddd
eeeeee
ffffffff
"""


In this case it didn't work out, do you have any ideas? Thank you once again =)

Comment: Oh my God, that's exactly what I have to do, I have a lot to thank. =)