# pythonic way to identify and remove sub strings from strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, numpy

I have a large numpy array of strings, where some elements of the array are good strings, some have special characters (typically at the start of the string and some have substrings in various quotes inside of it). I want to identify the elements which have a string inside of the string, store the string inside and remove it from my original string.

example:

```
my_array = ['# this is the "Sharpest" hashtag ever', 'life as we know it', '" what would you do?', 'this was an "arbitrary" result',  'what do you mean']

corrected_array = ['# this is the hashtag ever', 'life as we know it', '" what would you do?',
                   'this was an result', 'what do you mean']
```

As you can see the words "Sharpest" and "arbitrary" were removed from the corrected array.
Is there a way where I can identify the substrings and remove them from my original string efficiently

Comment: Some of the strings inside `my_array` are invalid, causing a syntax error.  You're going to have to fix that while you build that list.  Show the code for how `my_array` is created.

Comment: so you want to drop every string encased between quotes? As @GAEfan says,  `'# this is the 'Sharpest' hashtag ever'` is an invalid string, so you probably have to change the encasing quotes for the string or the substring

Comment: I just noticed that, the strings are valid in each element, it was a syntax error from my end when asking the question, but initial overall question stands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete the words between two delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784396/how-to-delete-the-words-between-two-delimiters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try a brute force approach in identifying the index associated to the first `"` and the similarily the last quote and then exempt all elements in the list where the first and last quotes are found

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import re
corrected_array = [re.sub('"[^"]*"', '', s.replace("'", '"')) for  s in my_array]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

[re.sub('["\']([^"]*)["\']', "", s) for s in my_array]
['# this is the  hashtag ever', 'life as we know it', '" what would you do?', 't
his was an  result', 'what do you mean']
```