# Regex with square brackets

Tags: python

I need to remove substring of a string bounded by the square brackets `[` and `]`. This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784396/how-to-delete-the-words-between-two-delimiters) shows how to do that with an example of `<...>`.

My example:

```
import re

s = "something something [1] another thing"
re.sub('[[^]]+]', '', s)
```

This is the output:

```
<input>:1: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
'something something [1] another thing'
```

The expected output is `something something another thing`.

How to regex in similar code dealing with square brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the literal brackets:

```
re.sub(r'\[[^\]]+\]', '', s)
```

This uses a raw string as without it the backslashes themselves would need to be escaped as in the following which does not use a raw string:

```
re.sub('\\[[^\\]]+\\]', '', s)
```

Comment: I came up with the same solution, but you might want to add why we should use a raw string here.

Comment: This to be clear for a complete newbie, "This uses a raw string" is referring to the first re.sub() example.