# how do i remove characters between 2 different characters inside a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

So i have this inside a text file :

`"00:00:25,58 --> 00:00:27,91 (DRAMATIC MUSIC PLAYING)"`

I want to remove characters inside and including the braces itself so :

`"00:00:25,58 --> 00:00:27,91 "`

```
eng_sub = open(text).read()
eng_sub2 = re.sub("\(", "", eng_sub)
new_eng_sub = re.sub("\)", "", eng_sub2)

open(text, "w").write(new_eng_sub)
```

I've tried using sub() and it removes a character but what i really want to do is manipulate characters between those 2 (i.e. "(" , ")") characters.

I don't know how to do it. thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete the words between two delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784396/how-to-delete-the-words-between-two-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

You may try matching on the pattern `\(.*?\)`:

```py
eng_sub = open(text).read()
eng_sub2 = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', eng_sub)

open(text, "w").write(eng_sub2)
```

Comment: `r'\s+\(.*?\)'` will remove any non printable characters (i.e. `\s+`)before the first `(`

Comment: but then i would have to do that manually each for different parts of the text because it looks like this,

**
11
00:02:23,04 --> 00:02:25,58
(ELECTRONIC MUSIC PLAYING ON SPEAKERS)

12
00:02:43,75 --> 00:02:45,08
You pay at the end.
**
and sometimes like this too,

**
27
00:03:27,41 --> 00:03:28,58
Behave.

28
00:03:30,75 --> 00:03:32,91
-(CHUCKLES)
-Oh, she's funny, ain't she?
**
so if i do that i would need to do it manually right?. or maybe im wrong

Comment: that was not indicated in the original question therefore noone could have guessed it. please provide more clarity concerning the possible inputs and expected outputs in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't use the "sub" method which will simply delete the pattern.
But what you can do (and which is not too complex) is to use "findall" (also present in the re library) which allows you to extract a pattern in the STR
Here's a simple example :

```py
import re
text = "00:00:25,58 --> 00:00:27,91 (DRAMATIC MUSIC PLAYING)"
print(re.findall(r"\(.*\)", text)[0])
```

Output: `(DRAMATIC MUSIC PLAYING)`

Once you have extracted what you want to manipulate, you can delete this pattern via sub

```py
print(re.sub(r"\(.*\)", '', text))
```

Comment: i love you so much <3