# How to delete text between two characters if conditions are satisfied

Tags: python, python-re

I want to detect text between two characters and delete the text including that two characters.
For Example:

1. choice(IN1T, endless )
2. choice("ENDMAN", endless )

In second example, the code would just pass that sentence and wouldn't change anything because after `' ( '` there is `' " '`, but in the first example, it would delete 'IN1T,' and the output would be for the first example:

> choice( endless )

Second example would be the same, as I mentoined before.
Output of the Second Sentence:

> choice("ENDMAN", endless )

I found already solution on similar question:
[How to delete the words between two delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784396/how-to-delete-the-words-between-two-delimiters)

The Answer of linked Question was:

```
re.sub(r'<.+>', s, '')
```

Similar thing that would maybe better explain the second thing I need this for:
Example:

1. {sometext here}

I would like to detect the written inside "{" and "}" and delete it if it is 14 characters or smaller including the curly brackets.

The thing is, I want to limit how much letters can be there, for example maximum 14 letters, as more letters would be invalid.
The above solution deletes text between "<" and ">" which isn't exactly what I need. I want it to pass the part of the sentence that starts with `"` because it would be something else completely.

Comment: `re.sub(r"\{[^{}]{0,14}\}", "", input)`

Comment: `re.sub(r"\{[^{]{,11}\}", "", input)` that will include curly brackets

Comment: What are the specific conditions? It's hard to extrapolate from just one example.

Comment: @Barmar , the text can't start with ' {" '.That is the most important condition.

Comment: There's no `{` in your first example `choice("ENDMAN", endless )`

Comment: @Barmar , it applied for both curly brackets and small brackets, they can't have ' " ' after the opening of them.

Comment: @Jurakin , can you just change "{" into "a" so it's clearer what is used for what?

Comment: The `\{` matches a literal curly; `{,11}` says to repeat the previous expression at most 11 times, preferring more repetitions if possible. The character class `[^{}]` matches one character which is not `{` or `}`.

Comment: @trilpleee ,  If I wanted to for example to set as a patter something that starts with ' ( ' and ends with ',' and there are only Uppercase letters, how would that exactly look like.Last question, there isn't so much information about this.

Comment: @Genius500 So the conditions you're talking about are the quotes around the first argument to the function? That detail should be in the question.

Comment: @Barmar , it's added to the First Example like a explanation, but I had mentioned the reason before at the End of the text.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead to exclude matching when there's a `"`: `re.sub(r'\((?!")[^,]+,', '', string)`

Comment: @Barmar , your solution works at some point, but I need to exclude other things because this text will contain Uppercase Letters and will have potentially '_'.That's my issue now, but you answered the part of the Problem, and tripleee and Jurakin answered another part.

Comment: Just put everything you want to exclude inside the `(?!...)` part

Comment: @Barmar , what If I wanted to only include text that is written with Uppercase.

Comment: That's even easier. `\([A-Z]+,`

Comment: @Barmar , just tested it, doesn't work for some reason, I can provide the actual text that I'm trying it on.
n(INIT_INI, ("Init_ini, )
I tried to make it delete INIT_INI,but it doesn't work could it be because of the '_' ?

Comment: We're not going to solve this in comments. Write a new question with a clear description of what you're trying to do (not like this question) and show the code you tried to write.

Comment: And make it a single problem, not a series of "what if I want ..."

Comment: @Barmar , that's the problem.I'm writing let's say some kind of Algorithms for my Compiler, it takes File from User, then it uses dictionary to translate the words in File, and after that, for cleaner File, I wanted to add Algorithm that will make File more Pure removing things I don't Want.It's Compiler for Code.It would be the easiest for me to share the entire code and people would be able to help me, but It's sensitive Code.I can't make an Example because it probably wouldn't work the same as my code because of different things that are used.Thank you for your help until now.

Comment: @Barmar , I understand everything.

Comment: This is not the right way to write a parser. Get yourself a copy of the dragon book.

Comment: @Barmar Okay.Got the book.Thanks for the advice.

Comment: The Dragon book is a classic but can be fairly intimidating. I remember hearing a recommendation for a lighter more recent book, probably from Red Hat's _Compiler_ podcast (which is by no means as technical as the name promises) a couple months back.

Comment: ... Drawing a blank so far, but came across this which is however also aging; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25840/can-we-stop-recommending-the-dragon-book-please